# How to re-render without window.reload()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, rendering

I am applying filter from model once the filter is getting applied the charts are not re-rendering on window.reload() only the filters are getting applied. But as we are making window.reload() the applied filters are getting deleted. I need after applying filters on reload the applied filters should not remove. untill users deletes

```
_handleFilterClick(chartId){
      let filterdefinitions = {
        dataSourceId: this.state.dataSourceId,
        filterDefinitions: this.state.filterData,
      }

      let data = {
        filterDefinitions: [filterdefinitions],
      };


      DashboardAction._ApplicableFilterToDashboard(data, this.props.params.dashboardId);
      DashboardAction._ApplicableFilterToChart(data, this.props.params.dashboardId, chartId);
      DashboardAction._saveFilterToDashboard(data, this.props.params.dashboardId);


}


export function _saveFilterToDashboard(data, dashboardId){
dispatcher.dispatch({
    type:'Loader',
    showLoader: true 

})
data = JSON.stringify(data);
let url = "/dashboardServices/saveFiltersToDashboard?userName=bigDataViz&dashboardId=" + dashboardId 
Api._callAPI( url, 'POST', data, (type,dt) => {
    if(type == 'success'){      

        if(dt.responseCode == 1){
            dispatcher.dispatch({
                type:'SnackBar',
                string: "Filter not updated successfully"
            })
            return;
        }
        if(dt.responseCode == 0){
            dispatcher.dispatch({
                type:'SnackBar',
                string: "Dashboard filter updated succesfully."
            })
            window.location.reload();
        } 
    }

});}
```

Comment: Did you try with the Hicharts function `chart.redraw()` ? [Api Doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.redraw)

Comment: no, I am using both c3 and highcharts both should reflect redraw method weill be applicable only to highcharts. I guess..!

Comment: where I need to call that function

Comment: Instead of the window.location.reload() function call, when your filters are applied successfully.

Comment: @DanielW sorry not able to understand.

Comment: @siva Replace the window.location.reload() with chart.redraw()

Comment: @DanielW chart.redraw will work only with high charts right? we are using c3 and d3 also will it reflect in other charts too?

Comment: @siva It will work only with higcharts

Comment: is there anything which supports all